# Using GCP for consuming the Apache Kafka topics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a requirement where I need to consume Apache Kafka topics via Confluent Cloud.

My web application is deployed in a GKE standard cluster, which has API and UI services running inside it.

Now I am analyzing the design for implementing the logic for consuming the Kafka topics.

Can someone give suggestions on which approach is right to use?

1. Can I create a service with the Kafa client running to consume the messages from Kafka topics within the GKE cluster?
2. Can I create the Google Cloud Run service with the above logic?
3. Can I go with sink connectors like the Google Cloud Function Sink Connector, Google Pub/Sub Sink Connector, and HTTP Sink Connector provided by Confluent Cloud?

If I have to go serverless using the Google Cloud-provided services, which will be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Cloud Run or GKE can run both Kafka Connectors or Consumers. You don't particularly need Confluent Cloud, unless that's where Kafka is available. You could also deploy Kafka into GKE and run on your own.

Comment: May I know, performance- and cost-wise, which one can be preferred? Cloud Run, or GKE

Comment: I am not a GCP user. GKE should have higher associated costs, based on more resources being necessary for running the more than the service itself